# Is it possible to decrease Ruby memory usage when streaming files?

Tags: ruby, http

I'm working on a class to download videos from an url.
I want to stream these videos instead of downloading them at once, so my program uses less RAM.

The function is the following

```
def get_file(url, max_segment_size)
  http_client = HTTPClient.new
  segment = nil

  http_client.get_content(url) do |chunk|
    segment.nil? ? segment = chunk : segment << chunk
    if segment.size >= max_segment_size
      # send part to s3
      send_part(segment)
      segment = nil
    end
  end
  # send last part
  send_part(segment) if segment
end
```

However, the program still uses a lot of RAM. For example, streaming a file of 30MB makes the process consume 150MB. Comparing to downloading the whole file at once, it uses about the same amount of ram. (I tried using net/http with the read_body method. Same results)

My understanding was that setting `segment = nil` should free up the space on the memory that the variable was using.

Is this expected to happen? Is there a way to manually free up this space on ruby?

Comment: not sure about Ruby but it looks like you can do it with nix if you separate the process into a different script. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1425/65890